# "как" в качестве или будучи

Tags: пунктуация

Весной 1945 года Василий как помощник тракториста пахал пашню день и ночь...Нужно ли выделить запятыми как помощник тракториста. Для меня Как здесь в значении "в качестве", а подходит и будучи+Подскажите. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Здесь больше подходит причинное значение оборота: пахал день и ночь, так как был помощником тракториста.

Значение "в качестве" можно было бы обозначить так: Весной 1945 года Василий работал как помощник тракториста и  пахал пашню день и ночь.

Comment: Значит, надо выделить запятыми. Спасибо, Вы мои сомнения развеяли. я как-то сомневалась в причинности.

Answer (score 0):

Но сама фраза звучит кошмарно. Именно вот это "как помощник тракториста".

Comment: Чего не бывает в великом и могучем. Я особой "кошмарности" не наблюдаю. Но это опять же - от вкладываемого смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Vera в основном. Значение здесь скорее причинное.
Хотя и "в качестве" однозначно нельзя исключить, не зная контекста. 
Может, его назначили подменять кого-то? Или еще что-то... 
А может, по мысли автора "помощник тракториста" - это такой "раб на галерах", который пашет день и ночь. Тогда это вообще сравнение...

Так что тут есть некоторая угадайка.

Comment: В любом случае я выделила запятыми. Спасибо всем.